# transition effect not working

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am trying to get button visibility with animated effect using CSS transition effect on hover but the effect is not working.

I am unable to find my mistakes, can anybody help me to solve my issue.

My HTML & CSS Code is as below.

```css
.prodiv3
{
 background-color:#d79e37;
 position:relative;
 z-index:999;
}
.product-box a
{
 text-decoration:none;
}
.prodiv3 h2
{
 padding:0px !important;
 margin: 0px !important;
 color: #fff;
 padding-left:15px !important;
}
.prodiv3 p
{
 color: #000000;
 padding-left:15px !important;
}
.link-icon
{
 position:relative; 
 bottom:120px; 
 left:10px;
 visibility:hidden;
 width:60px; 
 height:60px; 
 background:url(../images/link-icon.png) no-repeat center center #ff411c; 
 //display:block; 
 border-radius:100%;
}
.product-box a:hover .link-icon
{
 visibility:visible;
 -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in !important;
 -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in !important;
 -o-transition: all 1s ease-in !important;
 transition: all 1s ease-in !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 rowm">
            <div class="product-box">
                <a href="continuous_parison.php">
                    <div class="prodiv2">
                        <img src="http://aew.worldwebinfotech.in/images/card1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                        <div class="prodiv3">
                            <h2>Continuous<br> Parison Series</h2>
                            <p>Ranging from : 200 ML -5000ML</p>
                            <button class="link-icon"></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `transition` works with numeral values like `0` and `1` . and so it doesn't work with `visibility` or `display`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the transition to the main class. Not to the added effect/class.

```css
.prodiv3
{
 background-color:#d79e37;
 position:relative;
 z-index:999;
}
.product-box a
{
 text-decoration:none;
}
.prodiv3 h2
{
 padding:0px !important;
 margin: 0px !important;
 color: #fff;
 padding-left:15px !important;
}
.prodiv3 p
{
 color: #000000;
 padding-left:15px !important;
}
.link-icon
{
 position:relative; 
 bottom:120px; 
 left:10px;
 opacity:0;
 width:60px; 
 height:60px; 
 background:url(../images/link-icon.png) no-repeat center center #ff411c; 
 //display:block; 
 border-radius:100%;
 -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in !important;
 -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in !important;
 -o-transition: all 1s ease-in !important;
 transition: all 1s ease-in !important;
}
.product-box a:hover .link-icon
{
 opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 rowm">
      <div class="product-box">
        <a href="continuous_parison.php">
          <div class="prodiv2">
            <img src="http://aew.worldwebinfotech.in/images/card1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">         
            <div class="prodiv3">
              <h2>Continuous<br>
                Parison Series</h2>
              <p>Ranging from : 200 ML -5000ML</p>
              <button class="link-icon"></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry missunderstood. Edited.

Comment: sure! but another think. If i want to effect like this http://www.jagmohan.com/products.php

Comment: Whats up :-) ??

Comment: then what i need to do that

Comment: Therefor you need to add a transition for the overlay color and a transition for the vertical line up. To the .product-box

Answer (score 1):

Use `opacity`  0  and 1 instead of visitbility:

```css
.prodiv3
{
 background-color:#d79e37;
 position:relative;
 z-index:999;
}
.product-box a
{
 text-decoration:none;
}
.prodiv3 h2
{
 padding:0px !important;
 margin: 0px !important;
 color: #fff;
 padding-left:15px !important;
}
.prodiv3 p
{
 color: #000000;
 padding-left:15px !important;
}
.link-icon
{
 position:relative; 
 bottom:120px; 
 left:10px;
 opacity: 0;
 width:60px; 
 height:60px; 
 background:url(../images/link-icon.png) no-repeat center center #ff411c; 
 //display:block; 
 border-radius:100%;
}
.product-box a:hover .link-icon
{
 opacity: 1;
 -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in !important;
 -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in !important;
 -o-transition: all 1s ease-in !important;
 transition: all 1s ease-in !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 rowm">
                    <div class="product-box">
                        <a href="continuous_parison.php">
       <div class="prodiv2">
        <img src="http://aew.worldwebinfotech.in/images/card1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">         
        <div class="prodiv3">
         <h2>Continuous<br>
         Parison Series</h2>
         <p>Ranging from : 200 ML -5000ML</p>
         <button class="link-icon"></button>
        </div>
       </div>
      </a>
     </div>
    </div>
             </div>
```